# Javascript Concat three strings and send the new one in database

Tags: javascript

I'm working with a form that takes as input an email of a user and stores it in a database.
The problem is that I broke down the email to three parts->username,emailprovider,ending(.com,.edu etc). On submit it calls the function below.How can i get the new email(after concat) and store it in my database?I hope my explanation is specific enough.

```
function checkEmail(part1,part2,part3){
   var result=true;
   var notAllowed = new RegExp("/\W/");
   var email="";
   if (notAllowed.test(part1) || notAllowed.test(part2) || notAllowed.test(part3)){
    result=false;
   }else{
    email=part1.concat("@"+part2,"."+part3);
   }
   return result,email;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as your tagging PhP and need to send it to the database, you are doing it wrong.

I presume this is run on a website.
What you should do is use

```
$_GET["part1"]
```

and then concatenate them into a string. so you can easily write to your DB using sql statements in PhP

$fullemail = $string1 . $string2. $string3;

---

Edit:
why are you breaking it down if your going to concatenate it again?

Comment: I want to add later an option list for email providers and thought i could do it this way.

Comment: I would recommend you to show that in PhP. - Download the providers from database or whatever you like and then echo them all out in a div with hidden visibility and then make a javascript drop down list that edits the style =)! Or just only download certain providers :p

Answer (score 0):

You should use text/hidden file like

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />.
```

And assign value into input email element

Use following way instead of return value

```
document.getElementById("email").value = email
```

And then use post form to server.

```
document.forums['formName'].submit()
```

---

```
function checkEmail(part1,part2,part3){
   var result=true;
   var notAllowed = new RegExp("/\W/");
   var email="";
   if (notAllowed.test(part1) || notAllowed.test(part2) || notAllowed.test(part3)){
    result=false;
   }else{
    document.getElementById("email").value = email
   }
   document.forums['formName'].submit()
}
```

You can get posted values in `$_POST['email']` variable on server..

Try this for concat multiple strings , `+` operator is also same work

```
email=part1+"@"+part2+"."+part3;
```

Comment: Concat works just fine,the problem is sending the new value of email to the $_POST table so i can insert it as a whole in my database (using PDO).